# How to get window innerHeight etc. properties everytime it change to implement infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am trying to create an infinite scroll feature for a message box in an Angular7 project.

When it starts there are 10 initial items in the mail container. After user scrolls down to the bottom of page, it calls loadMore() method and retrieves 10 more messages.

However, the next time when a user scrolls down the callback triggers halfway down the page, the next time doing it just a quarter way down. After a while it is almost immediate once scrolling has begun, it continues to fetch data through the callback function.

I believe values in the callback function are not updating but I cannot seem to figure out why. Can anyone help me with this?

//Setting Event listener in onInit

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
  }
```

//Scroll callback function

```
scroll = (event:any): void=> {
  if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight){
    this.loadMore();
  }
  };
```

// loadMore() function

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.loadMore();
  }
```

Comment: There is a library that does exactly that. [you might want to check it out](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll)

Comment: Thanks for help but i don't want 3rd party.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver

Comment: Yeah it works but i've just see that is not working on Safari :/
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/a-modern-solution-to-lazy-loading-using-intersection-observer-9280c149bbc

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill